# Idiomatic approach for adding non-resource pages/functionality to rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Coming up to speed with rails and following a lot of the intro content, it's all based around "resources", so it feels like each of the CRUD operations on a resource have a view etc.

But real world applications often have feature-sets that don't fit this mold. For example, I have Users and Widgets that are owned by users.

Now I want to add something like "My Homepage", that one of my logged-in users will land on when they enter the app. Let's say this should be some kind of an "activity feed". The content of the feed isn't a model.

Or maybe I want a landing page for unauthenticated users to land on, and I want a bunch of other static pages.

It's not obvious to me what the general approach is for implementing new pages / functionality that don't exactly like up with new/edit/view of a specific resource. Of course I can fumble my way around this, but I'd like to learn what is considered to be the idiomatic pattern for doing this with rails.

Answer (score 0):

I think most people create a controller and some custom actions in it, but keep on following the naming conventions. For example if I need a static page I always create a `static_pages_controller` and inside that create an `index` or a `contact` method depending on the need. Then in the routes you can simple add it like this:

```rb
get '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', as: 'contact'
# This will create a /contact route that can called like contact_path and will go to the static_pages_controller contact action.
```